# Java - Handling generics with inheritance

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have a class that represents a vendor service and all their services have an authentication and an execute method.

I started thiking of an abstract class that represents this as below.
The thing is each of their services require a different request object, so I thought of using generics.
The problem is that if use it, I can't handle the specifics of each request object. Each children must use some methods from the type.

1) Should I try to make this way I'm trying, or remove this `executeRequest` method from the abstract class and each subclass implement it with the correct type?

2) I always hear "prefer composition over inheritance". Should I move the `executeRequest` to an interface?

Thanks in advance!

```
public abstract class VendorService  {

    private final VendorInitialization VendorInitialization;

    //a bean with some auth params
    public VendorService(VendorInitialization VendorInitialization) {
        this.VendorInitialization = VendorInitialization;
    }

    protected abstract <T> boolean validateRequest(T requestObject) throws VendorServiceBadRequest;

    protected abstract <T, P> P executeRequest(T requestObject);
}


public class VendorServiceAllocation extends VendorService {

    public VendorServiceAllocation(VendorInitialization VendorInitialization) {
        super(VendorInitialization);
    }

    @Override
    protected <T> boolean validateRequest(T requestObject) throws VendorServiceBadRequest {

        //List<BeanAllocation> requestObject = new Arraylist<>(); //I was using like this before

        //TODO: how to handle it as list of on this specific case?
        if (requestObject == null || requestObject.size() == 0) {
            throw new VendorServiceBadRequest(String.format("The list must have at least one element"));
        }

        //TODO: requestObject.get(0).getMySpecificFieldFromBeanAllocation will not work

        //some checks
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected <T, P> P executeRequest(T requestObject) {
        //executes and return a list of objects specific to this class
        return new List<BeanAllocationResponse>();
    }
}
```

Edit, for clarification:
In the child class `VendorServiceAllocation`, I need to use some methods that are specific of that type.

E.g.: Inside `executeRequest`, I need to call `requestObject.customFunctionFromChild()`

Comment: I think your abstract implementation is just fine; you just need to make sure that the functionality you abstract to the generic parent is useful for all of the children.

Comment: Thinking as a `executeRequest`, all children will use it. But if I think of the objects, each children will receive a different object. I should remove it from the abstract then? Or do you think I could use generics, something?

Comment: you're making the abstract methods generic while the class is not, instead make the class generic , then you could have sub-class Service1 that inherits `Parent<Integer>` and another that inherits `Parent<String>`(Integer and String are just examples for illustration )

Comment: oh nice!! this is what I was looking! 
the way you suggested, each children will know its type and I can work it.. 
please comment it as answer so I can mark it correct.. :)

Comment: It's not immediately clear if you need type parameters. I think just working with types as interfaces (e.g. make a `Request` class that `validateRequest` accepts)

Answer (score 3):

I think niceman hit the nail on the head, though I am not quite sure what you are asking. eg.

```
abstract class Service<T,P>{
    abstract public P processRequest(T t);
}
```

Then you can implement it in one of two ways.

```
class StringService extends Service<String, String>{
    public String processRequest(String t){
         return t;
    }
}
```

Or you could leave it to still be Generic and the actual instances would have the different types.

```
class OtherService<T> extends Service<T, String>{
    public String processRequest(T t){
        return t.toString();
    }
}
```

Where you could use it as,

```
OtherService<Integer> is = new OtherService<>();
```

Comment: this is exactly what I wanted.. I upvoted your answer, but I asked for @niceman to post his reply as an answer as he replied first.. hope you understand! :)